# Mongoose positional array update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following schema, and trying to update values in `answers.counter`.

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  question      : { type: String, required: true },
  answers       : [answerSchema]      
});
var answerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  answe         : String,
  counter       : { type: counterSchema, ref: 'Counter' }
});
var counterSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  upvotes       : { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0 },
  downvotes     : { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0 }
});
```

And the code:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(where, { '$inc': { 'answers.$.counter.upvotes': 1 } }, {'new': true, runValidators: true }, (err, post) => {
  if (err) return next(err);
  console.log('post=' + JSON.stringify(post));
```

So for the `where`, I have tried the following, among other variations:

1) `{ 'answers._id': ObjectId(${req.body.aid}) }`

2) `{ '_id': ObjectId(${req.body.pid}), 'answers._id': ObjectId(${req.body.aid}) }`

3) `{ '_id': ObjectId(${req.body.pid}), 'answers._id': ObjectId(${req.body.aid}) 'answers.counter._id': ObjectId(${req.body.cid}) }`

I am getting the following error:

`MongoError: exception: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: answers.$.counter.upvotes`

This is really baffling me because via mongo console, `db.posts.update({'answers._id': ObjectId('56ce1376ab820a5b3a149494')}, {$inc: {'answers.$.counter.upvotes': 1}})`

does correctly increments the right value, which started me on this whole path.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had a string instead of an object for `where`. So #1 in object form solved the issue:

```
let where = { '_id': req.body.aid }
```

Whereas previously it was in string form (using ${} template):

```
let where = `{ 'answers._id': ${req.body.aid} }`
```